# How to put dynamic data into a tooltip on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I have created simple chart that contains three circles. Each of those circles have coordinates. I tried to add a tooltip that displays coordinates of certain circle. Here is my attempt:

```
const data = [
  [90, 123],
  [120, 55],
  [55, 13],
];

const svg = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 200);

const circles = svg
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', (d) => d[0])
  .attr('cy', (d) => d[1])
  .attr('r', 10);

circles
  .on('mouseover', function (d) {
    tooltip
      .style('opacity', 1)
      .html(function (coords) {
        console.log(coords);
        return 'coords: ' + coords;
      })
      .style('left', 25 + 'px')
      .style('top', 75 + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', (d) => tooltip.style('opacity', 0));

var tooltip = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tooltip')
  .style('opacity', 0);
```

Unfortunately tooltip dont displays coordinates. Please help me fix this problem.

Here is a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dxcjw8?file=index.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for events changed from IIRC v6, so use:

```
circles
  .on('mouseover', function (event, d) {
  ...
```

Now `d` is available to `.html(...` and will be the relevant array from `data` so you can join the coordinates with `,` to populate the tooltip:

```
.html('coords: ' + d.join(', '))
```

Working example:

```js
const data = [
  [90, 123],
  [120, 55],
  [55, 13],
];

const svg = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 200);

const circles = svg
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', (d) => d[0])
  .attr('cy', (d) => d[1])
  .attr('r', 10);

circles
  .on('mouseover', function (event, d) {
    tooltip
      .style('opacity', 1)
      .html('coords: ' + d.join(', '))
      .style('left', 25 + 'px')
      .style('top', 75 + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', (d) => tooltip.style('opacity', 0));

var tooltip = d3
  .select('body')
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tooltip')
  .style('opacity', 0);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  background: rgb(194, 235, 235);
  overflow: visible;
}

svg .tick line {
  stroke: white;
}

svg .objects-layer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

svg .axes-layer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```